# Better way to write this? Increase Speed?

Tags: php, mysql, post, proxy

I wrote the following PHP script to work with an HTTP proxy for content filtering. The proxy POSTs to this script the URL of the site the user is trying to visit. The script (obviously) checks the site for keywords that should be blocked, then responds to the proxy. It takes too long to navigate between pages with this. Currently.... about 3 mins. per page.

**Here is that code:**

```
<?php

$location = $_POST['Location'];
$user = $_POST['User'];
if($location == "") {
  die("Invalid Request! Missing Parameter 1!");
}

if($user == "") {
  die("Invalid Request! Missing Parameter 2!");
}
$con = mysql_connect("MySQL Host", "USER", "PASS") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("DBName", $con) or die(mysql_error());
$query = "SELECT `Policy` FROM Subscribe WHERE `Username`='$user'";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
if(mysql_num_rows($result) == "1") {
  $nothing = "nothing";
} else {
  die("Invalid User!");
}
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $policy = $row['Policy'];
}
if($policy == "0") {
  echo "allow";
  exit;
}
if($policy == "4") {
  $query1 = "SELECT `Address`, `Keyword` FROM Policy WHERE `Owner`='$user'";
  $result2 = mysql_query($query1) or die(mysql_error());
  while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
    $address = explode(',', $row['Address']);
    $keyword = explode(',', $row['Keyword']);
  }
} else {
  $query2 = "SELECT `Address`, `Keyword` FROM Policies WHERE `Policy`='p".$policy."'";
  $result2 = mysql_query($query2) or die(mysql_error());
  while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
    $address = explode(',', $row['Address']);
    $keyword = explode(',', $row['Keyword']);
  }
}

if(in_array($location, $address)) {
  echo "deny";
  exit;
} else {
  $meta = get_meta_tags($location);
  $keywords = $meta['keywords'];
  $keywords = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $keywords); 
  $keywords = str_replace(' ', '', $keywords);
  $keywords = explode(',', $keywords);
  while (list($key, $val) = each($keywords)) {
    if(in_array($val, $keyword)) {
      echo "deny";
      exit;
    }
  }
  $urlk = explode('.', $location);
  while (list($key, $val) = each($urlk)) {
    if(in_array($val, $keyword)) {
      echo "deny";
      exit;
    }
  }
}
echo "allow";
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 3mins/page is highly doubtful, but the `else` part of the code:

```
if (in_array($location, $address))
```

is a bottleneck due to the disk I/O and keyword matching involved.

See if this helps (without caching):

```
else {    
    $meta=get_meta_tags($location);
    $keywords=explode(',',str_replace(' ','',$meta['keywords']));
    $urlk=explode('.',$location);
    if (array_intersect($keywords,$keyword) || array_intersect($location,$urlk))
        echo 'deny';
}
```

Comment: It is a problem with the Proxy itself. It seems to only work once, then it doesn't go to the next page until I restart it. I'll post that in another question. This bit of code sped up the time it took for the PHP script dramatically, so I'll give this one to you.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using GET instead of POST? Technically they should be the same speed, but the proxy might be doing something odd with POST to prevent multiple requests.

Here's a quick example of how to use GET instead with urllib:
http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#examples

Exactly how long is "way too long"? You could try timing it compared to accessing the site without the proxy.

Also, you might want to do some other profiling to see where the bottleneck resides. Is it your python script, your connection to the internet, the PHP script or the PHP host? Is the PHP site on a shared host? It might be snappier if you had a dedicated or VPS.

Another thought, you could try adding some caching on the PHP side. If the same user keeps hitting the same site(s) over and over, there's no sense in querying the database each time.

Comment: Way too long = 3 mins.(ish) per page. I have done some testing and discovered that the speed issue lies in the PHP script. Yes, it is on a shared hosting server. I like the idea of caching, but don't even know where to begin with that. I'll go ahead and remove the Python script from my original post.

Comment: I'd ask your host if they provide memcached, I'm going to guess they don't, but if they do there are plenty of tutorials on the internet on how to implement memcached with PHP. Alternatively, you could try this database abstraction library (http://adodb.sourceforge.net), as it allows you to easily cache database queries. It would also be easier to implement than memcached.

Comment: How did you determine it was your PHP script? I still say you should try converting both your python/php scripts to use GET instead of POST and see what happens. Even if it doesn't fix the issue, it will allow you to time/tweak your PHP script directly, via your browser. See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php for an example of timing a script.

Comment: I changed it to use GET. It turns out, it is the Proxy that is slowing everything down. I think it might not be handling persistent connections correctly or something.

Answer (score 1):

`$query1/2` and `$result1/2` can be overwritten very easily by calling them with the same name. It will not make any problem at all. Also mysql result vars are very heavy.

To check if a variable is empty there's a php native function that also check if the variable is equal to NULL, '', or is not set at all: `empty($var)`. I'd use it for the first part of your code instead of `$var == ''` that is not elegant neither.

Also `mysql_num_rows()` returns an integer, and you are comparing that result with a string with value "1". I'd correct it with: `mysql_num_rows($result) == 1`.

We have also the problem of

```
  echo "deny";
  exit;
```

wich can be replaced with `exit('deny');`

I still doubt that a page takes 3 minutes to load, maybe 3 secs?

Answer (score 0):

The way you've pasted it, it looks like the call to ProxyRequest.process(self) is not done inside your process method.

Comment: sorry... that was an error when pasting. I corrected it above.

Comment: If you say it takes about 3 minutes, look if you handle persistent connections properly.